# Alt-F4 not shutting down pc anymore on Xubuntu 20.04.2.0

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, shutdown, login-screen, logout

Since a few weeks Alt-F4 is not shutting down my pc anymore on Xubuntu 20.04.2.0. I get the login screen and from there I can shutdown the pc, but it asks if I am sure because there might be other programs running.

I tried updating (commands "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get upgrade"). I looked in the "keyboard" program to see if there is another program fixed to Alt-F4. That is not the case.

Thank you!! Still very much in love with Xubuntu, after all these years.

Comment: FYI:  I'd check your system has all upgrades applied (`sudo apt full-upgrade` maybe needed), as a fully upgraded 20.04 system will report as 20.04.5 and not 20.04.2.   You can refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/ for date, but installed systems upgraded on the weekend before that date; the date being the ISO release date.

Comment: Sorry, My os-release was 20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa). Version 2.0 was my first version.